# OneToMany: reference to parent entity is not up to date in child after parent was updated

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a classical one-to-many relation. I read list of child entities from database using session.createQuery() approach to filter only required small amount of child entities. Each child has reference to the parent entity. Then I update some fields of the parent entity and save it (see in logs and db that changes were persisted). But when I get parent from any child entity like child.getParent() it still returns reference to the parent object with fields values before update.
When a new child entity is constructed instead of reading it from db using session.createQuery() then the problem does not appear - the fields of the referenced parent entity contains actual values.
What could be a problem with beans got using session.createQuery()? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't you think the code would help finding the problem in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the "changed Parent" to the child once more:

```
Parent parentToUpdate;

...
child.setParent(parentToUpdate);

...
session.persist(child);
```

If you want to transmit the change into the database you should also persist them.